# Can I bind to an ancestor DataTemplate in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I'm having trouble pulling off a binding that I believe should be valid in Silverlight 5:

```
<Controls:GraphLayout>
  <Controls:GraphLayout.VertexTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox ... />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Controls:GraphLayout.VertexTemplate>
  <Controls:GraphLayout.SubgraphTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Controls:GraphLayout VertexTemplate="{Binding VertexTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:GraphLayout}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Controls:GraphLayout.SubgraphTemplate>
</Controls:GraphLayout>
```

This is a simplified example but hopefully it's pretty readable.  In excessence I'm trying to bind the VertexTemplate of the SubgraphTemplate to the VertexTemplate of the containing control (the root GraphLayout control).  Unfortunately, in the code behind I can see that VertexTemplate is null in the subgraph control.

Answer (score 0):

May be your code *can* work (this is strange that you bound to something that **doesn't** have an `x:Key` and I think you should use `{StaticResource  SomethingWithName}`)).

But actually what you looking for is [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx). It's very easy to use and actually support the logic you described.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think a DataTemplateSelector solves the problem since I'm not trying to bind to a parent's template, not choose a template based on something.